# I forgot to vent steam my canner for the 10 minutes while pressure canning my green beans

Tags: canning, beans, botulism

I worked up my green beans, cleaned them, and boiled them for about 15-20 minutes.  Filled the jars(hot packed), added my clean boiling water, and then put in the pressure cooker.  After a week, I remembered that I didn't let it vent steam for 10 minutes.  Once it started steaming well, I placed the weight on it and let it build pressure. After reading up on this, I found that it could possibly be contaminated with botulism.  Should I toss them out, or will boiling before eating them be safe?

Comment: Premium users going on question-closing frenzy as it seems.

Comment: @MentallyHealthyPerson It seems like a clear duplicate to me. If you disagree, you should explain why or suggest an edit.